# Connecting to MySQL Cluster from WCF

Tags: wcf, connection-string, mysql-cluster

I have configured server to use MySQL Cluster.
The Cluster works fine.
This is my server architecture:

Server 1: Cluster Manager: 10.176.133.219

Server 2: Data Node & Sql Node: 10.176.168.129

Server 3: Data Node & Sql Node: 10.176.137.66

My Question:
I have a WCF Service where I have put the connection string when I had 1 database (directly the server IP as database host).
How do I connect to the Cluster? How is the connection string written?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connectionString="Data Source=10.176.168.129, 10.176.137.66;database=myDB;user id=myUsr;password=myPass"

the solution is putting the hostnames (address) as comma-separated.